# Copying azure VM from one account to another

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azcopy

I created an Azure VM some time back and need to copy it to another account as the new account has a subscription with more credit.  I am trying to copy the vm however cannot find the vhd uri.  I wanted to use AzCopy.  When I click on disks from the Settings menu I see a resource ID which is not a url.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: it seems your vm create by managed disk, if you want to Azcopy it to other account, we should copy it to storage account then copy to another Azure account.

Comment: Yea the VM was created by Managed disks.  However I do not find the vhd in any storage accounts.  I checked through Azure Storage explorer.  I am baffled.  It should nt be so hard to find the vhd.  I also created a new VM but did not find VHD for the same too.  What am I missing?

Comment: We can use powershell to copy vhd from managed disk to another unmanaged disk direct, please check my answer:)

Answer (score 3):

> Now how do I move this snapshot to a different azure account to create
>   a VM of this snapshot.

We can't copy or move snapshot to different Azure account direct. If you want to move this snapshot, we should use this snapshot to create a managed disk and copy this managed disk to another storage account.

So we can **use PowerShell to copy VHD from managed disk to unmanaged disk**, then use this new VHD to create a new VM.

We can do that with PowerShell command:

```
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName "[ResourceGroupName]" -DiskName "[ManagedDiskName]" -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read  
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName "[StorageAccountName]" -StorageAccountKey "[StorageAccountAccessKey]"
$blobcopy=Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer "[ContainerName]" -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob "[NameOfVhdFileToBeCreated].vhd"
```

After copy completed, we can use the new VHD to create a VM.

Here a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566291/is-it-possible-to-convert-azure-vm-from-managed-disk-to-unmanaged-disk/45569760#45569760), please refer to the answer.

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.

1. VM Settings:

[image: VM Settings]

2. Disks Settings:

[image: Disks Settings]

3. Properties For One Disk:

[image: Properties For A Disk]

Comment: Probably Jason Ye is correct - perhaps your VM was created by managed disk. Please follow his suggestions if it's the case. :)

Comment: Yea the VM was created by Managed disks.  However I do not find the vhd in any storage accounts.  I checked through Azure Storage explorer.  I am baffled.  It should nt be so hard to find the vhd.  I also created a new VM but did not find VHD for the same too.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ok further I found with managed disks you cannot find the vhd.  but need to create snapshot.  I did so.  Now how do I move this snapshot to a different azure account to create a VM of this snapshot.

Comment: @user1552466 Good to hear that you've resolved the problem by yourself. :)